# What causes Emacs to maximize on startup?

Tags: frames, start-up

I have just move to MS Windows 10, and installed emacs.  Emacs starts with the frame maximized.  I don't want that.  I tried the -geometry option.  First an initial frame is evident.  Then a smaller frame corresponding (I think) to the -geometry specification.  Then the frame maximizes.

How can I prevent that maximization?

I grabbed a .emacs file from the Internet that set up some defaults that I like. This default behaior is one I don't like, but I can't see where in the .emacs file this it is specified.

Comment: Unless this is a Windows 10 thing-a-majig, Emacs should *not* start with the frame maximized if there is no user-configuration.  Try with zero user-configuration, aka `Emacs -Q` and verify that Emacs is *not* maximized on startup.  Then, bisect your user configuration and find out where you are maximizing it.  Adding `toggle-frame-maximized` is likely *undoing* something you have done earlier in the startup process.  As such, adding `toggle-frame-maximized` (to the end of the `.emacs` file) is almost certainly the *wrong* answer (or it is *inefficient* at best).

Comment: I'm running Emacs 25/26 on Windows 10 and don't see this behavior, so agreed this is likely some local configuration issue.

Comment: @glucas I'm sure it is, thanks.  I grabbed a .emacs file from the Internet that set up some defaults that I like.  This default behaior is one I don't like, but I can't see where in the .emacs file this it is specified.  When I first posted, I couldn't figure out how to un-do it.  I eventually found a way, and posted it as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Adding (toggle-frame-maximized) to the end of .emacs did the job.